# If statement in function creates additional objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

The function is supposed to add objects to a nested array(Items) in an array of objects and checks whether the object already exists. If it does exist it just increments the quantity, otherwise it should add a new item. However, once the nested array (Items) has a second object, it creates new objects instead of incrementing even if the condition (array[i].items[x].description == _description ) should return true. The _description and _quantity values are passed from user inputs.

```
var array = [];

AddCustomItem = function (_title, _description) {
if (array.length > 0) {
    for (var i in array) {
        if (array[i].RoomName === "Other") {                        
            for (var x in array[i].Items) {
                if (array[i].Items[x].description == _description) {
                    array[i].Items[x].quantity += parseInt(_quantity);
                    break;
                } else {
                    array[i].Items.push({
                        category : "Other",
                        description : _description,
                        quantity : parseInt(_quantity)
                    });
                    break;
                };
            };              
            break;  
        };
    };
} else  {
    array.push({
        RoomName : "Other",
        Items : [{
                category : "Other",
                description : _description,
                quantity : parseInt(_quantity)
            }
        ]
    });
};
var result = array;
return result;
```

};

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. What is your problem with the code, what does not work as expected? Please [edit] your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding if the **first entry** of the array isn't a match, and not looking at any other entries in the array since you `break;` out of the array in both the `if` and `else` blocks. So the loop never loops. Instead, search the *entire* array, and then only add if you didn't find the entry.

Here's a minimal-changes version:

```
var found;
for (var x in array[i].Items) {
    if (array[i].Items[x].description == _description) {
        found = array[i].Items[x];
        break;
    }
}
if (found) {
    found.quantity += parseInt(_quantity);
} else {
    array[i].Items.push({
        category : "Other",
        description : _description,
        quantity : parseInt(_quantity)
    });
}
```

...but I'd probably use [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead (you may need to shim it on older browsers):

```
var found = array[i].Items.find(function(item) { return item.description == _description; });
if (found) {
    found.quantity += parseInt(_quantity);
} else {
    array[i].Items.push({
        category : "Other",
        description : _description,
        quantity : parseInt(_quantity)
    });
}
```

---

Side note 1: `for-in` isn't usually a good way to loop through arrays. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476) describes your various choices for doing so.

Side note 2: The block attached to `if`, `for`, etc. doesn't need a `;` after it. The block is already terminated by the `}`.

Answer (score 1):

However, once the nested array (Items) has a second object, it creates new objects instead of incrementing even if the condition (array[i].items[x].description == _description ) should return true.

That is because you have break after outer for and there is no second iteration it just adds element in else statement.

Answer (score 0):

> it creates new objects instead of incrementing even if the condition
>   `(array[i].items[x].description == _description )` should return `true`

That is because this condition **will not always return true**. Since there will be other items in the array as well.

In your logic, it will go to else the first match doesn't happen.

You need to do

```
     var found = false;
     for (var x in array[i].Items) 
     {
            if (array[i].Items[x].description == _description) {
                array[i].Items[x].quantity += parseInt(_quantity);
                found = true;
                break;
            }
     }
     if (!found) {
                array[i].Items.push({
                    category : "Other",
                    description : _description,
                    quantity : parseInt(_quantity)
                });
                break;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that on the first pass through your inner loop, you always either update the quantity or add a new item, and then you break out of the loop. You need to let it loop through all the items until either a match is found, or you run out of items. Then, if no match was found, you add an item. See my code below. It uses a boolean variable to indicate if a match was found or not.

```js
var found = false;

for (var x in array[i].Items) {
  if (array[i].Items[x].description == _description) {
    array[i].Items[x].quantity += parseInt(_quantity);
    found = true;
    break;
  }
}

if (!found) {
  array[i].Items.push({
    category: "Other",
    description: _description,
    quantity: parseInt(_quantity)
  });
}
```

Bonus tips:

- `for` loops and `if else` blocks don't need a semicolon after the closing `}`
- your declaration of the `AddCustomItem` function will be a global variable, since you didn't declare it with `var` (unless you already declared the variable with `var` earlier)